# Does Clang-LLVM work for iPhone?

Tags: xcode, clang-static-analyzer

I am currently using Xcode 3.2.1 for learning the iPhone SDK and was wondering if its possible to use the Clang-LLVM and the static-analyser to aid in debugging my code. Currently I am using the default templates, but swapping the compiler in project>settings gives me errors when compiling for the simulator. Is this possible?

gary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no.

You can use the Clang static analyzer on your Objective-C code (with the Build and Analyze menu item), but you cannot use clang or llvm-gcc4.2 to build an application.